# Send SMS from website to mobile without using SMS gateway

Tags: java, php, sms

Is there any way to **send SMS from website to mobile without using SMS gateway**?

Any other alternative ways...

Any help/suggestions really appreciable.

Comment: Once i created the android app which takes data from website and sends to mobile number. so you can use android app to do so.

Comment: Check this https://www.servage.net/blog/2012/01/27/sending-sms-to-cellphones-from-your-website/

Answer (score 1):

You can send SMS using devices like a Phone or GSM Modem directly connected to computer via USB.

If it's an android phone: You may try [PDANet](http://pdanet.co/) (a tethering program) will let you send and receive SMS via a little desktop client when you are connected to your phone via USB or bluetooth.

If it's GSM Modem you can try [This](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp)